# Node proxy web sockets how to check

Tags: node.js, sockets, proxy, websocket, node-http-proxy

I use the following module and it works fine for reverse proxy
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
currently I've used the code like the following example

```
httpProxy.createServer({
  target: 'ws://localhost:9014',
  ws: true
}).listen(8014);
```

my question is how can I **check/simulate** that the websockets are working?
Any test will be helpful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to the OP's request for browser test, I modified my original solution to proxy both HTTP and WS traffic to a server where an `index.html` file is served.  This file then connects the browser to the proxy server via WebSocket, which the proxy then proxies to the main server.  A simple message is printed on the browser document from the main server.

So that there is no need to copy/paste anything, I created this repo with full instruction: https://github.com/caasjj/httpproxy.git

Here is the code in case others want to look at it here.  To run the whole thing, create the two server files and the `index.html` file, start the servers with `node proxyreceiver.js` and `node proxyserver.js` and then navigate to `localhost:8014/index.html`.

(`proxyserver.js`):

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var http = require('http');

var proxy = new httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9014
  }
});
var proxyServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res);
});

//
// Listen to the `upgrade` event and proxy the
// WebSocket requests as well.
//
proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});

proxyServer.listen(8014);
```

(`proxyreceiver.js`):

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(9014);

function handler (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
      res.end(data);
    })

}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('data', { message: 'Hello World!' });

  socket.on('resp', function(msg) {
    console.log('Got message: ', msg);
  });

});
```

(`index.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Web Socket Proxy Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:8014');
    var p = document.createElement("p")
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log('Got', data);
       p.innerHTML = "Received:" + data.message;
       document.body.appendChild(p);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test ProxyServer</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much 1+,I created those 3 files and start the node app and didnt get any error, the issue is that when I put in the browser the url(like in the post 8014/9014) nothing happen even in the console,any idea what is missing?Do I need additional step (im new to this topic :))

Comment: Please note that we are not returning any renderable html to the browser.  Your original question just needed test code to verify the connection, and that's how I wrote the answer.  Were you able to see the client connect to the server, have the request proxied and then get a response?  If so, that verifies that the web socket connection is working through the proxy server.  If you need browser test code, I will need to provide you additional code.

Comment: Updated with test code to run on browser.  Please let me know if this is closer to what you needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I clone it from git and start the two files, when I run the index file I got the test ProxyServer but how I acatully test the webSocket when I  put in the url localhost:8014/index.html noting happen in console I see Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8014/index.html net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED any idea?

Comment: Second question is assume that I dont need the second server in my scenario ( this server is created by other program and I need just to proxy to it calls ans ws how would I adopt the code than,Thanks in advance expert!

Comment: The error is because the proxy can't connect to the main WS server.  Please make sure you have the ports exactly as I have them, both servers are on the same machine, no firewalls, etc.  For your 2nd question, it depends on the configuration (port #) of your main server, but you shouldn't need to change much.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test is to create a client to connect to it.
there are many ws modules around. Or you can use this: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html just put your url there and test it.

Comment: Can you please provide example how can I create client to connect to it?

Comment: just use the one i provided in the link. If you want to create a client you can use node.js and use a module called `ws`